# Prolog: incrementing variable

Tags: prolog, global-variables

I'm a beginner in studying prolog. I have some problem to do this: I want create a global variable and incrementing this variable. I did in this way:

```
assert(X,10).
inc(X,Y):- Y is X+1.
```

But I have this error:

```
   ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

Comment: You are thinking in a very imperative way of assignments. In Prolog, a variable is not supposed to change but it is in relation to another variable. In this case you would define a predicate suc(X,Y) :- X is Y + 1. The query would then be suc(10, Z). Anyway, arithmetic is probably not the easiest way to start. There are introductory books like Clocksin & Mellish: Programming in Prolog but the others mentioned in answer 8 of the [comp.lang.prolog FAQ](http://www.metalevel.at/faq/faq.html) should also be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, in Prolog it's better to avoid at all [global variables](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=gvar). But if you badly need them...

```
:- dynamic my_counter/1.

my_counter(10).

increment :-
  retract(my_counter(C)),
  succ(C, C1) /* or C1 is C+1 */,
  assertz(my_counter(C1)).
```

SWI-Prolog has an idiom I have seen used right today: [flag](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=flag/3)/3

From [pl-fcgi](https://github.com/keriharris/pl-fcgi) intro, an high performance global counter for a fastcgi server

```
service_request :-
    flag(count, N, N+1), ...
```

to know the value, you can use

```
?- flag(count, C, C).
```